To divide some items into some groups on average, how many types of division occur and what is the probability of each occurrence?
First of all, it must be pointed out that these items are not at all the same kind and not at all the different kind.
let me give an example: there are 4 items: "A,A,B,C" divided into 2 groups and each group contains 2 items. So there are 2 types of division with corresponding probability:

(AA), (BC), $1/3$
(AB), (AC), $2/3$

The probability can be treated as sampling 2 items in order without replacement. Like the probability for sampling (A,A) is $2/4\times 1/3=1/6$. (B,C) is $1/4\times 1/3=1/12$. so as the (C,B). So the whole probability is $1/3$.
Here comes the question for general situation: given $n$ items and $m$ groups with $m|n$. These items contain $k$ kinds and the number of each kind is $n_k$, $\sum\limits_k n_k=n$. How many types of division occur and what is the probability of each occurrence? Is there a formula to describe it?
